# What's the way to translate model attributes in rails with mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3, translation, mongoid

I've problem with mongoid and model translations. When I'm trying use mongoDB on my model I haven't idea to translate attributes and model name. It's normally in *.yml files but in this time this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 16):

Variant with "activemodel" does not work for me. But.

This variant worked for me:

```
 en:
  mongoid:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email:
              blank: "You have to give me your e-mail address"
              not_found: "e-mail address not found in list of members"
              #...
    attributes:
      user:
        email: "Email address"
        name: "Your nickname"
        #...
```

[From here](http://bitprison.net/mongoid_model_attibutes_translation)

Answer (score 7):

Try this in the yml file (config/locales/pt-BR.yml in my case):

```
 activemodel:
    attributes:
      [model_name]:
        [attribute1]: "[translation1]"
        [attribute2]: "[translation2]"
        [attribute3]: "[translation3]"
```

Worked for me, using mongoid 2.0.0.beta.17 and rails 3.0.0

Comment: What about translating the name of the model itself?

Comment: Works perfect with mongoid 2.7.1!!

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
mongoid:
  attributes:
    article:
      title: "Article title"
```

Check this one: https://gist.github.com/lurkermike/1596505

Answer (score 0):

If you use engines you have o namespace the model

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      'my_engine/mymodel':
        one: TranslatedMyModel
        other: TranslatedMyModels
    attributes:
      'my_engine/mymodel':
        myattribute: translated attribute
```

or if you use **mongoid**

```
en:
  mongoid:
    models:
      'my_engine/mymodel':
        one: TranslatedMyModel
        other: TranslatedMyModels
    attributes:
      'my_engine/mymodel':
        myattribute: translated attribute
```

I solved it using comments from [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9148) issue.